# Is there a root password on OS X and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, osx, password, root

When you setup a new Ubuntu or OS X installation a user is generally created for you. On OS X it is whatever username you pick. On Ubuntu (the server version) usually the `ubuntu` user is created.

The way I understand it, there is also a root user, which you can access via something like `sudo su - root`, and entering the password of the `ubuntu` or the user you created, which is part of the administrators group. Once you switch to `root` I think you can use the `passwd` command and change root's password.

**But what was `root`'s password before that?** Does it exist? Is it a random string of numbers and letters? How does the system deal with that?

Comment: On Ubuntu, you only need `sudo su`. The `root` account is assumed by default.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `su` is only needed for switching to some *non-root* user. To run a single command as root, type `sudo command`. To get a root shell, type `sudo -i`.

Comment: And if you tell someone on the ubuntu forums how to set a root password, or boot and reset a user password via a livecd, it can get your account banninated for 30 days... ask me how I know....   The Ubuntu folks *really* don't want you having a password set for root, they want you to always use sudo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can answer only for Ubuntu.
In Ubuntu the `root` user has a locked password. From `passwd` man page:

> ```
>    -l, --lock
>            Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a 
>            password by changing it to a value which matches no possible 
>            encrypted value (it adds a '!' at the beginning of the password).
> ```

You can see the `!` in `/etc/shadow`.

A user with a locked account cannot change its password, but root can, without prior entering of the old password.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how to unlock (?) or create an actual root user in OSX:

1. System preferences
2. Users & Groups
3. Login options (click lock and authenticate here)
4. Click "Join" (NAS)
5. Open Directory Utility
6. Click the lock (authenticate again)
7. Edit menu -> enable root user
8. (Edit menu -> change root password)

Enjoy !

Comment: +1 for the good description of the Mac GUI. I only ever knew the command line way to activate the root account.

Comment: Yeah, I was amazed when the Apple Customer Care guy walked me through the steps to do this...I figured it's too good of a secret to keep "hidden".

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204012 for the official doc on this.

Answer (score 7):

As enzotib said, Ubuntu has a root account but it's locked by default.

Now, about Macs:

As you can probably guess, root (along with all the daemon accounts) doesn't appear in the "Users & Groups" section of Settings.

Looking at my mac's `/etc/passwd`, there is an entry for `root`, along with a message

```
Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
in single-user mode.  At other times this information is provided by 
Open Directory.
```

I tried to find the Open Directory user list, without success, but in the configurations there were mentions of explicitly giving root permissions even though they're implied.  I was never prompted for a root password when I first set the machine up, so I'd guess the root account is locked as it is in ubuntu.  I didn't (and don't really want to) try giving root a password and logging in with it, but you probably could.

The passwd line:

```
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
```

The perl command from keith's comment adds a `:0` to the end.  No password hash.  There's no shadow file I can find either, I haven't been able to find them anywhere to check whether root might have a password.

Comment: What is the output of `perl -e 'print join(":", getpwuid(0)), "\n"'` ?  (**NOTE**: If it includes something that looks like a hashed password, don't post it here.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Posted it, nothing special.  I know about the hash, but I appreciate you including the warning for users who might not.

Comment: What about the same Perl command with your own uid?  Does that show a hashed password?  (Again, obviously, don't post the hash.)

Comment: @KeithThompson it has 8 asterisks instead of just the 1.  And it's not in /etc/passwd.

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps `getpwuid()` on MacOS does that deliberately, to avoid revealing sensitive information (though there has to be *something* that can access the hashed password).

Comment: I've been searching online and it seems they had a shadow in the last os but I can't find one in lion.

Answer (score 7):

The root password on Mac OS X is stored (as mentioned by Kevin) in Open Directory. To confirm the existence of the root user a simple grep is required:

```
$ grep ^root /etc/passwd 
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
```

To read the root password information from Open Directory:

```
$ dscl localhost -read /Local/Default/Users/root Password
Password: *
$ dscl localhost -read /Local/Default/Users/root AuthenticationAuthority
No such key: AuthenticationAuthority
```

In the default case (as shown), the root user does not have a password hash set (the account is locked). You can compare this setting with the value in OD for a "normal" user:

```
$ dscl localhost -read /Local/Default/Users/normaluser Password
Password: ********
$ dscl localhost -read /Local/Default/Users/normaluser AuthenticationAuthority
AuthenticationAuthority: ;ShadowHash;HASHLIST:<SALTED-SHA512>...#rest of hash data
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu sets up a password for the named user and uses it for superuser (root) level tasks as installing and deleting system wide software and directory and file deletion/execution beyond your home directory. A root account is in fact in place but without an assigned password a bit hidden. Canonical, and Ubuntu usage conventions, in effect discourage you from directly invoking it.

It sets up a named user account rather than setting up a generic "ubuntu" account. That is at least the case with installed systems. A generic "ubuntu" account maybe in place if you use a live CD, I can't remember, I have not worked with a live CD in a couple of years.

The behavior in MacOsX is actually quite similar. You are asked to set a password, which is invoked each time you attempt to do superuser level tasks such as installing or upgrading software but there is no account named "root".

Comment: I believe there in fact a root "user". You can `su` to root, root has a home directory, and files can be owned by root. Can you provide some citation to your argument that there is no root account?

Comment: Certainly there's an explicit root account (uid 0, name "root").  There has to be on any Unix-like system.  It just doesn't have a password (at least by default).  You can even get a root shell: `sudo bash -l`, then type `whoami`.  (But normally you should use `sudo` for individual commands rather than having an interactive shell running as root.)

Comment: You maybe correct, I am not questioning you. If there is a root account, then they have done a good job hiding it. I also use Fedora on some of my machines and VMs and root is very much an active account.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu:
by default you can access your newly created user account.

To run any command as root you can use

```
sudo command
```

then enter your normal password.

The root account is by default locked. To activate root by command line just enter

```
sudo passwd
```

then enter your logged in user's password and then new passwords for root. Now you can log in as root using `su`
and then enter root's password.