# What was superuser password set?

Tags: root, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a root password on OS X and Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26006/is-there-a-root-password-on-os-x-and-ubuntu)

After I installed Ubuntu, I noticed that I'm not sure what was superuser password set, If I set it at all.
I know that I created a user via which I'm logging in.
But when I write `su` command the password for the user I created does not work.

Does it mean that superuser is the one user I created and I can use `sudo xralf` to gain superuser privileges? Is there some material on this topic. I'm still little confused how this works in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a regular Ubuntu install, you never explicitly set the root user password. You can still however `su` to root easily by typing `sudo su -` in a console when logged in as the first regular user you created (which has sudo privileges).

I presume that the password is set to something random and unknown to any human, for security reasons, although this always seemed a bit strange as compared to other distros where you do set a password for root before even creating any other users.

---edit---

As per Kevin's answer, the password is not random as  I had suspected, but initially disabled (follow the link in his answer for further details).

Comment: Not random, as I mentioned it's disabled entirely.

Comment: you can if you like enable the root account with sudo passwd

Comment: @Kevin edited answer to aknowledge this

Answer (score 4):

On a default Ubuntu install, the root account is locked, which is implemented by storing into the password hash field a value that cannot be a legal hash.  See more details here: [Is there a root password on OS X and Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26006/11750)

Comment: You can flag a question to be closed as a duplicate when this happens. "flag -> it doesn't belong here (which makes no sense in this case, but oh well) -> exact duplicate"

Answer (score 0):

Iirc in ubuntu 10.04 I could do:

```
sudo /bin/sh
```