# I can login as root on the X-Window terminal but I cannot login as root on the console

Tags: terminal, login, root, console

I can login as root on the terminal
but not on the console
what is the problem?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The sudo command lets you **execute** a command as another user (such as root) if you are part of the sudo-group. You do not actually **log in** as that user.  The password you use with the `sudo` command is the password of the account you are currently logged into.

Logging in as root on tty2 (your first screenshot) would be the same as running the `su` command on the X-window terminal.

Comment: then can i login as root from the start?
or do i have to borrow the authority of root by sudo command every time i log in?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26006/5132 shows what this answer is missing.

Comment: For security reasons you usually do not want to login as root at boot (you could change this of course but it is not recommended to do so). What you can do is execute the `su` command in the X-window terminal and login as root and type `exit` after you are done to drop back to your original account. Or indeed prefix the command with `sudo` ([see this answer for executing multiple commands without typing sudo everytime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382060/change-default-sudo-password-timeout)).

Comment: Or do what you did by spawning a new shell with `sudo -i` / `sudo sh`